# Add special characters and background colour

Tags: jsf

I am working on validation of a user registration form. What JSF tags can I use to add special characters and background color to that registration form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it forms unique tags for you in input field:
http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with "special characters", but I assume that you mean "special fonts" or something. In general, to style a webpage you should use CSS. You can set the font type by `font-family` property and you can set the background color by `background-color` property.

First create a `style.css` file with the following content:

```css
.yourFormClass {
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Then put it in public web content (there where your JSF pages also are) and then declare it in the `<head>` (or `<h:head>` if you're using JSF 2.x):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Then you can use the `styleClass` attribute of any containing JSF component to let JSF generate it as `class` attribute in the final HTML element.

```html
<h:form styleClass="yourFormClass">
```

*(open page in browser, rightclick and "View Source" to see it)*

To learn more about CSS (which is a completely separate subject from JSF), check the [CSS tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net/). Keep in mind that JSF is basically just a HTML code generator.